# Using Spark to extract part of the string in CSV format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark newbie here and hopefully you guys can give me some help. Thanks!

I am trying to extract a URL from a CSV file and the URL is located at the 16th column. The problem is that the URLs were written in a strange format as you can see from the print out from the code below. What is the best approach to get a the URL in correct format?

```
case class log(time_stamp: String, url: String )

val logText = sc.textFile("hdfs://...").map(s => s.split(",")).map( s => log(s(0).replaceAll("\"", ""),s(15).replaceAll("\"", ""))).toDF()


logText.registerTempTable("log")

val results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM log")
results.map(s => "URL: " + s(1)).collect().foreach(println)

URL: /XXX/YYY/ZZZ/http/www.domain.com/xyz/xyz
URL: /XX/YYY/ZZZ/https/sub.domain.com/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz
URL: /XXX/YYY/ZZZ/http/www.domain.com/
URL: /VV/XXXX/YYY/ZZZ/https/sub.domain.com/xyz/xyz/xyz
```

Comment: Let me get this right, you want to cover the extracted URLs from `/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/http/www.domain.com/xyz/xyz` to a "normal" form like  `http://www.domain.com/xyz/xyz`?

Comment: do you always have the same" /XXX/YYY/ZZZ/" in frond? Three sections of letters separated by a "/"?

Comment: No. The /XXX/YYY/ZZZ are pretty random. And it could be more than 3 sections.

Comment: More than 3 letters or always 3 letters?

Comment: That could be random too... it could be /vvvvv/xx/yyyy/zzzzzz/http/........

Answer (score 6):

You can try `regexp_replace`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1L, "/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/http/www.domain.com/xyz/xyz"),
  (2L, "/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/https/sub.domain.com/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz")
)).toDF("id", "url")

df
  .select(regexp_replace($"url", "^(/\\w+){3}/(https?)/", "$2://").alias("url"))
  .show(2, false)

// +--------------------------------------+
// |url                                   |
// +--------------------------------------+
// |http://www.domain.com/xyz/xyz         |
// |https://sub.domain.com/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz|
// +--------------------------------------+
```

In Spark 1.4 you can try Hive UDF:

```
df.selectExpr("""regexp_replace(url, '^(/\w+){3}/(https?)/','$2://') AS url""")
```

If number of sections before `http(s)` can vary you adjust regexp by replacing `{3}` with `*` or range.

Comment: Thanks zero323. I am using Spark 1.4.1, does it mean the regexp_replace will not be available for this version?

Comment: Yes it does. You can try corresponding Hive UDF but if you work with DataFrames you should upgrade to 1.5+ anyway.

Comment: Thanks but i got this following error

java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: regexp_replace

Comment: Like I said it is Hive UDF. If it cannot be found there is a good chance you don't use `HiveContext`.

Comment: Thinks zero323. As you said,  I dont have HiveContext but i can get around it by using the Scala's replaceAll function. But it seem that your suggested regexp doesn't match the first 3 sections of /xxx/yyy/zzz . I have been playing with different way but still no luck. Do you have any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: I think i may get it now zero323. The /XXX/YYY/ZZZ may contain special character such as "." or "-" in it.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, `\w` matches only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If there is something else going on there you'll have to adjust the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The question comes down to parsing the long strings and extracting the domain name. This solution will work as long as you don't have any of the random strings (XXX,YYYYY, etc.) be "http" and "https":

```
def getUrl(data: String): Option[String] = {
   val slidingPairs = data.split("/").sliding(2)
   slidingPairs.flatMap{ 
       case Array(x,y) => 
          if(x=="http" || x == "https") Some(y) else None
    }.toList.headOption
}
```

Here are some examples in the REPL:

```
scala> getUrl("/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/http/www.domain.com/xyz/xyz")
res8: Option[String] = Some(www.domain.com)

scala> getUrl("/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/https/sub.domain.com/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz")
resX: Option[String] = Some(sub.domain.com)

scala> getUrl("/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/a/asdsd/asdase/123123213/https/sub.domain.com/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz")
resX: Option[String] = Some(sub.domain.com)
```